# About google map licensing

Tags: google-maps, license

We are having a client which is looking to develop a service provider directory , which will be provided free of cost to end users nothing commercial for end users they can use it with out any charges.

End users will be able to search providers on the directory and result of search will be show on google maps also end users will be able to  search directory pointing different locations on map so directory will show results for that particular location itself.

Everything for End user is going to be free. But the service providers are going to be charged for their subscriptions and that will be minimal plus some part of this charges will go do different charities.

So question is that do they have to take Google Enterprise version? Or Google free version will do?

Thanks,
Naresh.

Comment: Did you check out the [Google Maps API licensing page](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing)? You will get authoritative answers by asking Google directly - there is a contact link on that page.

Comment: Google Enterprise is required if the Business is making money from Google Services, appropriate licensing is required.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Now, i will check there. Thanks,
Naresh.

Comment: @katahdin Please mark this as answer.

Comment: @Mapperz: I'm pretty sure that You don't require a License just because you are making money from Google service. It is much more complicated, but as long your website is free for the end user, and within the usage limits, you don't need the Enterprise version. (https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1)

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Google Maps API licensing page](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing).  There you will find a table with the differences between the free Maps API and the paid Maps API for Business.

As @Devdatta Tengshe pointed out, Google's terms do include some exceptions (see [Section 9.1](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1)). It's best to contact Google directly - there is a contact link on the first link above - because they will help you find the path that doesn't put your site in conflict with Google's terms. I have worked with them directly and can tell you that they will not pressure you into signing up for the paid service.

Comment: I think this is perfect answer : )

Answer (score 1):

All.
Thanks, for your reply. I talked with Google sales department. They replied, if our site contain map , which use to make money, or if it in secure side means used after login page then we need to take enterprise license, otherwise we can use it free.

Thanks all of you. :)

Comment: Please check mark the appropriate answer

Comment: Hi, Sunil.
Sorry for my silly question.
How i check mark the answer  ?

Comment: I think you are not the creator of this question so you can't : (

Comment: I have posted this question , Sunil. !!!!!

Comment: When i click on UP arrow on left side, the msg is : to Voteup , require 15 reputation. might be i am newbie. :)

Comment: Hi Sunil, I have posted another question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54054/multiple-response-from-nominatim-service-call-geocoding-in-openstreetmap. In that i can see the tick mark to mark the answer as accepted, but in this question, i can't see it. :)

Comment: Please check http://gis.stackexchange.com/about &  http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Yes, Sunil. I mention that things, before your comment. Please see it. I can't see that TICK MARK. :)

Comment: @Naresh You cannot see the Tick mark, because you had asked the question as 'user15889'; That is a different account than the one you are currently using. You could post a request on meta.stackexchange.com asking for both these accounts to be merged.

Comment: @Naresh, please see [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/contact/user-merge) for how to merge user accounts.